# Loop through directory zip folders with bat and 7zip

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I am trying to loop through a directory with folders in it.
I want to compress the folders trough 7zip (As some of them are really big files)
What I mean with this is as example:

- Main folder

  - Backup 1
  - Backup 2
  - Backup 3

I want it so that it creates for the folders Backup 1-3 each a separate 7zip file.
Here is what I got:

```
@echo off
set zip=7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on
set directory="E:\Backup\"
for /d %%i in (%directory%) do %zip% "%%i.7z" "%%i%\*"
pause
```

But as soon as I do it like this, it just creates 1 7zip file called Backup, it does not make a seperate 7zip file for each folder inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it almost done.

```
@echo off
    set "zip=7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on"
    set "directory=E:\Backup"
    for /d %%i in ("%directory%\*") do %zip% "%%~fi.7z" "%%~fi\*"
    pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another option:

```
@echo off
cd /d "E:\Backup\"
set zip=7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on
for /d %%i in (*) do %zip% "%%i.7z" "%%i%\*"
```